# Почему idea не видит entity при валидации HQL

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, hql

Использую Hibernate 5.2.3.Final. У меня есть entity ExternalGrade которая выглядит максимально обычно(и такая проблема со всеми entity)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при составлении запросов на HQL idea не видит эти entity и указывает на ошибки в запросе.

Конфигурация у меня в xml, возможно это из за неё?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property> <!-- Используется с 03.11.2021 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5000</property> <!-- Используется с 03.11.2021 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">25</property> <!-- Используется с 03.11.2021 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">30</property> <!-- Используется с 03.11.2021 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property> <!-- Используется с 03.11.2021 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">25</property> <!-- Используется с 03.11.2021 -->

</session-factory>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал настраивать facets, который выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А add framework support даже не хочет открываться, и в поиске показывается только если показывать выключеные действия [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось что в facets нужно было подключить JPA поддержку, а не Hibernate, что привело к созданию файла persistence.xml, который по сути своей является заглушкой, что бы idea понимала что нужно подключить поддержку фреймворка.